# Style values of array found in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an array containing words that need to be styled if found in a string, but I'm struggling to make it work correctly.

Here is my code, as you can see I'm looping both the array and the table containing my strings.

in the first string, only 1 word (venkel) is being picked up and replaced but only once also. I need all the words in the array to be replaced if found in the strings by bold values.

**UPDATE** when using Regex, not every words update

```js
var productName = ["witte asperges", "crème fraîche", "wijtingfilet", "selder", "BIO wortelen", "BIO rode ui", "venkel"],
  descriptionName = document.getElementsByClassName("Description");
for (var i = 0; i < productName.length; i++) {
  var product = productName[i];
  for (var x = 0; x < descriptionName.length; x++) {
    var description = descriptionName[x];
    if (description.textContent.indexOf(product) !== -1) {
      descriptionName[x].innerHTML = descriptionName[x].textContent.replace(product, product.bold());
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:60%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Spoel ondertussen de wortelen goed schoon en snijd de wortelen en de selder in blokjes van 2 cm. Verwijder het stugge uiteinde van de venkel en snijd in plakjes van 2 cm. Voeg de venkel, de wortelen en de selder toe aan de pan en laat 4 min.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Spoel de aardappelen en boen ze goed schoon. Snijd ze in blokjes van 3 cm en kook ze in zo’n 10-15 min. beetgaar in lichtgezouten water.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Giet de crème fraîche bij het vispannetje, breng op smaak met een snuifje zout en flink wat zwarte peper en laat 3 min. opwarmen. Dien het vispannetje op met de puree. Smakelijk!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Be aware that method of making a string bold is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold)

Comment: @Jamiec thanks, I will consider an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression for the global replace on your `product` variable like this:

```
new RegExp(product,"g");
```

You also need to change the code to `descriptionName[x].innerHTML = descriptionName[x].innerHTML.replace(reg, product.bold());` for changing the HTML content and not the text content with bold.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
var productName = ["witte asperges", "crème fraîche", "wijtingfilet", "selder", "BIO wortelen", "BIO rode ui", "venkel"],
  descriptionName = document.getElementsByClassName("Description");
for (var i = 0; i < productName.length; i++) {
  var product = productName[i];
  for (var x = 0; x < descriptionName.length; x++) {
    var description = descriptionName[x];
    if (description.textContent.indexOf(product) !== -1) {
      var reg = new RegExp(product,"g");
      descriptionName[x].innerHTML = descriptionName[x].innerHTML.replace(reg, product.bold());
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:60%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Spoel ondertussen de wortelen goed schoon en snijd de wortelen en de selder in blokjes van 2 cm. Verwijder het stugge uiteinde van de venkel en snijd in plakjes van 2 cm. Voeg de venkel, de wortelen en de selder toe aan de pan en laat 4 min.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Spoel de aardappelen en boen ze goed schoon. Snijd ze in blokjes van 3 cm en kook ze in zo’n 10-15 min. beetgaar in lichtgezouten water.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data Description">Giet de crème fraîche bij het vispannetje, breng op smaak met een snuifje zout en flink wat zwarte peper en laat 3 min. opwarmen. Dien het vispannetje op met de puree. Smakelijk!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit, but notice the word "selder" isn't being picked

Comment: @Jonathan You need to change ` descriptionName[x].innerHTML = descriptionName[x].innerHTML.replace(reg, product.bold());` see the updated answer and let me know if it is still missing something

Comment: Excellent. thanks! so I was only missing the regex part